# React Native adds new data when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native and I am new to javascript. I have a problem with my code that i can't seem to find where the error is.

My app has a user that can add and save plate numbers. The problem is everytime I save the plate or click the add button or just plainly click the plates that are already saved, it duplicates itself

Here is my code for this one

```
export default class plakaco extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            plates: [
                {plateNumber: '', status: '', id: 1},


            ]
        }
        this.getPlateId = this.getPlateId.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        let newArr = this.state.plates.slice(0);
        let idPlate =  this.state.plates[this.state.plates.length - 1];
        let newId = idPlate.id + 1
        newArr.push({plateNumber: nextProps.pn, status: 'Saved', id: newId})
        this.setState({
            plates: newArr
        })
    }
     componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("id").then(val => {
            this.setState({
              "id": val
            })
            fetch(`http://aaa.com/api/getClientPlates/${val}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({})
            }).then(response => {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                })
            })
        }).done()
    }
  getPlateId(i, plateNumber, inputEditable){
        this.props.getValues(plateNumber, inputEditable, false, false);
  }

    addAPlate(){
        this.props.getValues('', true, true, true);
    }

  render() {
    return (
            <View style={styles.leftView}>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.addAPlate.bind(this)} 
                    title="ADD"
                    color="#343434"
                    accessibilityLabel="Add a plate."
                />
                <PlateItems plates={this.state.plates} getPlateId={this.getPlateId}/>
            </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  leftView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F1F1F1'
  }
});
```

Here is the code on where i clicked a plate and it keeps adding the same plate over and over again

```
_onPress(i){
        this.props.plates.filter((val) => {
            if(val.id === i){
                this.props.getPlateId(i, val.plateNumber, false, false);
            }
        });
    }
  render() {
      const listItems = this.props.plates.map((item) => 
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress.bind(this, item.id)} key={item.id}>
            <View style={styles.lists} >
                <Text style={styles.itemText1}>{item.plateNumber}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.itemText2}>{item.status}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
```

[Here is a sample image of no plates added or saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmlHD.jpg)

[Sample Image with save plates that duplicates itself whenever it is click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN7M4.jpg)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the code i came up with a solution that the error might be in `componentWillReceiveProps` and please change

```
this.state.plates[this.state.plates.length - 1];

to 

newArr[newArr.length - 1];
```

Cheers :)

Comment: still the same sir. When i click an existing plate it duplicates

Comment: When your item.id is unique then there is no need to use filter.. use indexOf

Comment: what? @Codesingh